# Crime lords not pitching up at table

Tags: evil-genius

I have done the tasks on the global map to get the 3 crime lords, but it doesn't show in the task list that it is completed. Also, the crime lords don't come to the island. What must I do?

And also, [Nikita Leonov](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Nikita_Leonov) doesn't come to the island either for capturing. I need help getting further with this game. This problem is the 2de task of the game.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "2de task"?

Comment: I mean it is the 2de task of the game "Head of the underworld"

Comment: I see. It's been a long time since I last played the game, so I'm not familiar with its terms anymore.

Comment: Don't you mean the second task of the game, and not the "2de task"? 2de sounds like something Dutch. It seems that you are referring this mission: http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Objective_2#Sub-objective_2

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've completed the Acts of Infamy for  Nigel Ewing, Armand Krishnan, Marvin de Luca, and Lei Ying Lo.  If you have, and you've built the Inner Sanctum room and placed the Conference Table in it, they should be sitting around the table, waiting for you to finish up.  If you haven't built the Sanctum or the Table, the crime lords will mill about like tourists until you do.

Nothing further happens with these guys until you've dealt with Nikita and Bob.

Nikita Leonov is *not* a girl, as you'd specified in your original question.  He's an African man with a large hairdo and a brightly colored coat.  He should be wandering around your island.  You have to capture him, put him in a cell, and use the '[advanced mess hall counter](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Human_Mixer)' to interrogate him.  Once you've done this, he will go to the conference table as well.

Bob Caine will sent an assault force to your island, which you will have to repel.  Once you've done this, Bob will be willing to come to your conference table as well.

At this point, and only at this point, can you trigger the cutscene that completes this objective.  There's a point-by-point walkthrough on the [Evil Genius Wiki](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Objective_2) that might make a good reference if this didn't solve your issue in particular.

Comment: I have built the inner sanctum and the coverence table and everything the crime lords just aren't there even though I did the mission and it also doesn't say completed even though I did

Comment: I don't know what to tell you past that - my only advice would be to try to work on the current objectives the game's given you.  It's possible that it's a bug, but I don't believe there are any known bugs related to this mission...

Answer (score 1):

Conference Table is the answer. It's a game bug.

The very first Conference Table that you build is the only one that can progress the story.

If for some reason your first Conference Table was destroyed (perhaps by demolishing the room), then any following Conference Tables will not trigger story progression.

Load an earlier savegame or start new game. Either way, all three initial crime lords MUST sit at the very first Conference Table that you've built.